# how rename series legend in chart created by views

Tags: views, charts

I created a chart page by using Views. But the legend is always Series 1, Series 2. Not using the label data.

[image: generated chart]

I tried to find the option to replace the label "Series" with the label from the data, but I could not find it. 
Anyone can help me how to use the label of the data instead of "Series"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I can find the answer, after keep on trying:
I have to switch to custom label. Just change to custom label in the field.

[image]